# Eliminating Null Values in Avg DateDiff

Tags: reporting-services, null, average

I am currently using **SSRS** and **BIDS** and am running into an issue when computing my average of a date difference function.

My function to get rid of the Nulls works fine in the Date difference function:

```
=iif(IsDate(Fields!Date_Responded.Value),DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, Fields!Date_Received.Value, Fields!Date_Responded.Value), "N/A")
```

My problem is I cannot get an average function to eliminate the null values.  It currently works where groups that do not have null values but doesn't calculate anything for groups that have nulls

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!Date_Responded.Value),"",(Avg(DateDiff(DateInterval.Day,Fi‌​elds!Date_Received.Value, Fields!Date_Responded.Value), "Letter_Type")))
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What is the code you are using for Average?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  Here is what I am using but instead of eliminating the Nulls it is eliminating any group that has a null and not returning any value for average.  Other groups that do not have a null value are still working fine.                    =IIF(IsNothing(Fields!Date_Responded.Value),"",(Avg(DateDiff(DateInterval.Day,Fields!Date_Received.Value, Fields!Date_Responded.Value), "Letter_Type")))

Comment: Can you add the code from your comment and add to description as this will help others as they may not see it in the comments. Also can you clarify the logic .. `If date is nothing then display "" else if Average number of days between two dates ? (greater/less then/equal to) then "Letter_Type" else ? end`

Comment: I updated my original post.  I am just trying to get averages without taking into account null values.

Comment: One option is in your dataset to set a default value that you can use to get the average before displaying on the report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The aggregation should be the outermost expression, not within the `IIF`:

```
=Avg(IIF(IsNothing(Fields!Date_Responded.Value), Nothing, DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, Fi‌​elds!Date_Received.Value, Fields!Date_Responded.Value)))
```